# phishing site called stackoverflow.hex1.ru?

Tags: discussion, security

When searching on google for `SKVideoNode render video sphere` it comes up with a Stackoverflow result only from `https://stackoverflow.hex1.ru/questions/tagged/scenekit`

it looks phishy to me.

[image: stackoverflow.hex1.ru]

When I click on said link chrome warns me that my connection isn't private..

Is this some sortof phishing site, or is this perhaps a russian alternative to Stackoverflow?

What exactly is going on here & what can we do against this?

Comment: My Kaspersky antivirus suite warns me that that site is a known distributor of malware so proceed with caution.

Comment: @Magisch most likely a phishing site? what could we do about this?

Comment: What do you want us to do? DDOS it?

Comment: @Gerwin How about you report it to Stack Exchange under the "Contact Us" Form at the bottom of every page?

Comment: No, but you could contact google & make them black-list it.

Comment: @Magisch that has been done, I just wasn't 100% sure if it was just my chrome & antivirus giving a false-positive or if it was actually malicious.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi would be interesting if question ban message directed banned users to that site

Comment: It appears they're also scraping buzzfeed so if you care that much you can contact buzzfeed's legal team too

Comment: @JonasCz it's not actually a duplicate, as this website has malicious content and is dangerous for those who google & trust SO answers.

Comment: Yes, bit you can report it to Stack Exchange anyway, and they'll deal with it all the same, malicious or not.

Comment: Their IP address is now banned http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318793/17373