# I don't know why my account id have appeared on other domain?

Tags: discussion

When I search my stackoverflow account on google , some other result also display . Look at under link , is it some subdomain of stackoverlow ? If not, can they retrieve my data from stackoverflow...?

http://www.hnhjbaby.com/users/4395287/david-jorhpan

Comment: It's a [scraper](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253906/what-should-i-do-about-a-clone-service-scraping-stack-exchange-sites-for-content). I don't know if user profiles fall under the CC BY-SA license.

Comment: And this is not the only such site. See also [phishing site called stackoverflow.hex1.ru](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317257/1016716), [stackoverflowr.com proxying stackoverflow.com for phishing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363388/1016716), [Site duplicating Stack Overflow, potential privacy/security issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287439/1016716), [4 Fakes Stack Overflow Sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296142/1016716) etc. And there's this one, that seems not to have been reported yet: `http://howtucode.com`

Answer (score 13):

Sites like the one you linked scrape Stack Overflow for answers and questions, and then repost them on their own.

The CC BY-SA license that Stack Overflow content falls under requires attribution, so if the scraper is doing it properly that means that your username and a link to the real thing should also be in there as attribution.

In this case it seems they just scrape the whole site including user profiles. You can report scrapers you believe to be in violation of the licensing requirements to Stack Overflow directly using the [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) form.

Comment: You can also theoretically go after illegal scrapers yourself (given that, from all I can see, Stack Overflow doesn't seem to be doing much in that department.)   Those scrapers dumb enough to run their site through an American hosting company can be hit by a DMCA notice, I think (but I'm no expert and have never done this. It's probably not worth the effort in most cases unless you're seeing your name or likeness misrepresented in some egregious way.)

Comment: @Pekka웃 You mean going after a licensing violation (violating the license you have given stack overflow) via DMCA takedown request? Wouldn't Stack Overflow need to file that since it's their license that is being violated?

Comment: Before I report such a scraper, is there a list of reported ones already?

Comment: @Magisch you licensed *use* of your content to Stack Overflow in a certain way and under a set of conditions, but it's still your content. If someone else uses the content under conditions you didn't agree to, you can absolutely go after them yourself.

Comment: @Pekka웃 A DMCA request can only be made by the owner of the content, or their designated representative.  You cannot just submit a DMCA request on behalf of some random person.

Comment: @Servy the idea is that David JorHpan would have standing as owner of content he created, _if_ that site violates the Share Alike Attribution license.

Comment: @Servy `You cannot just submit a DMCA request on behalf of some random person.` yes, but I did not suggest that (perhaps I was not clear enough.) I meant you can go after scrappers misusing *your* content, not other SO users'